# What kind of mount does this Chinon 70-210mm AF Zoon lens have?

Tags: nikon, lens-mount, adapter

I have an old Chinon lens which I want to mount on my Nikon DSLR. I know there are some adapters on the market, but I can't figure out which mount my CHINON has.

In the "specialist shop" they told my something like "not possible", but after Google research I found out that there are Adapters for almost all old Chinon lenses.

See attached pictures...[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you light the mount a little better with the side that contains the aperture actuator towards the camera? It hard for me to see what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nikon has a high [flange focal distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flange_focal_distance), the distance between the film/sensor and the bayonet. Pentax K/M42 have a lower distance. So you can't attach your lenses "close enough" to the sensor. You will either lose the ability to focus on infinity or you need an adapter with a glass element that will significantly decrease the optical quality of the combination, not talking about the quality of the lenses itself and their suitability for digital cameras (the sensor reflects more light than a film, so there are more reflections within the camera).

If you have a Nikon it is probably not worth adapting old lenses. If you really want to use that old lenses use a Canon or a Pentax. In this case the latter would be the right choice, the lens caps even says "PK" (Pentax K).

Comment: What version of the Pentax K mount has eight electrical connections inside the bayonet lugs? the most I've seen inside are two, with the rest of the connections on the outside ring.

Comment: Chinon and Ricoh used the basic K bayonet but added their own AF pins. So it works as a manual lens on current Pentax cameras. (Wait, is there even a focus ring at that specific lens?)

Comment: thanks for your answer, as said in the commet to @MichaelClark answer, the further part where the lens cap sits can be turned as a whole to focus. but you think there is no user for the adapter Yao Bo Lu mentioned in his link to amazon?

Comment: So you could manually focus adapted to a Canon AF mount, but how would you control the aperture?

Comment: @MichaelClark that's a good question. i can not see a aperture ring. so you are right about the adapter... pity!

Comment: @Elias Not very much use in that adapter. You can't set the aperture, you have an additional glass element that reduces the quality (and it really does!). If you have a Pentax you could try this lens; I don't see much gain in adapting it to other systems. (I personally use a Pentax for exact that reason.)

Answer (score 1):

That lens is made to work with the Chinon CP-9AF, an early auto focus film camera. The basic mount is the same as the Pentax K Mount, but the electrical contacts are located differently. Chinon only made three lenses in this mount: a 28-80, a 35-135 (very rare) and the 70-210mm that you have.

Pentax K Mount lenses will work as manual focus lenses on the Chinon CP-9AF. You would also need to manually focus the Chinon 70-210mm lens on a Pentax body (which might be a little awkward) by turning the barrel just behind the lens cap.

Since there is no aperture ring on the lens, you would need a post-1983 Pentax or Chinon body with Pentax K-A, K-AF, K-AF2, or K-A2 connectors to operate the aperture lever using the camera to select the aperture setting. If you used an adapter to use the lens on any non Pentax body you would have no way to control the aperture.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer! there is the possibility to focus manually. the further part where the lens cap sits can be turned as a whole to focus!

Answer (score 0):

From what I could find is that Chinon uses either a m42 mount or a Pentax k mount. From the article at [SLR Lens Mount Identification Guide](http://rick_oleson.tripod.com/index-99.html). It looks like your lens is a Pentax K mount. It seems like you can find [adapter for this lens to Nikon F mount](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003Y31A2W). But using it you will need loose for example auto-focus ability of the lens (read the description of the adapter)